# Не отображаются картинки в файле html

Tags: html, изображения

Не отображается локальная картинка в файле html.

```
<img src="projectSphynx\dev\images\orange-square.jpg" alt="orange-square">
```

Вместо картинки отображается маленький значок и текст из alt. Браузеры: Chrome и Firefox. Редактор - Visual Studio Code. Адреса верные - я использую "копировать относительный адрес" к изображению. Также при попытке открыть ссылку через Ctrl+ЛКМ внутри Visual Code пишет ошибку: "При загрузке изображения произошла ошибка."

Что пишет консоль в Хроме, когда картинка внутри div:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

В пустом body где только картинка:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/projectSphynx/dev/projectSphynx/dev/images/orange-square.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Открываю и через Live Server, и просто через браузер из папки.

Comment: Дело в том, что пути к файлам пишутся не с обратным слешем, а с обычным "/"

Comment: С обычным слешем проблема сохраняется.

Comment: попробуйте ```http://127.0.0.1:5500/images/orange-square.jpg```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает.

Comment: можете выгрузить на сервер  и дать ссылку?

Comment: У вас только это изображение не загружается или остальные тоже? Возможно просто битый файлик

Comment: Файлик сделал в Paint у себя за пару минут до работы с файлом. Также не грузится таблица со стилями (пишет то же самое - 404). Как выгрузить на сервер - не соображу пока...

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что проблема кроется в путях к файлам? Во вкоаде Explorer в VSCODE (иерархия) лежать те файлы, которые види проект. Может у вас картинка находится где-то вне проекта?

Comment: https://github.com/daniel-uv/first-project Вот, залил всё на гитхаб в том виде, который у меня на ПК.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeworks\dev\first-project\style.css">
<img  src="homeworks\dev\first-project\images\orange-square.png"> 

Заменить на
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<img  src="images/orange-square.png">

Нужели не работает?

Comment: Не поверите... Проблема всё ещё на месте.

Comment: а зажмите на клавиатуре шифт и обновите страницу

Comment: Не помогает. Что-то странное творится..

Comment: Попробовал у себя. Такая же проблема. Как я понял картинка битая или что с ним не так. Когда поменял формат картинки на .jpg картинка появилась, потом когда обратно вернул png так же все работает